# Animations on Flutter application using FlowBuilder, Navigator 2.0 and BLOC pattern

Tags: flutter, navigation, router, bloc

I was implementing a simple app to study Navigation 2.0 with the BLOC library and of FlowBuilder for Flutter I noticed that during the transition between views the animations are not played.

I created a router method:

```
List<Page<dynamic>> onGenerateAppViewPages(
  AppState state,
  List<Page<dynamic>> pages,
) {
  SelectedPage selectedPage = state.selectedPage;
      switch (selectedPage) {
        case SelectedPage.home:
          return [
            const MaterialPage(
              child: MyHomePage(title: 'Hello',),
            ),
          ];
        case SelectedPage.addCardToCollection:
          return [
            const MaterialPage(
              child: Page2(),
            ),
          ];
      }
}
```

Then I used it on my MaterialApp widget:

```
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: FlowBuilder(
        state: context.watch<AppBloc>().state,
        onGeneratePages: onGenerateAppViewPages,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I have two simple wiews with one TextButton which changes the status of the AppBloc and switch from one screen to the other, but the animation doesn't work, what am I doing wrong? Here is the result:

[image]

Full code here: https://github.com/paste94/flutter_application_1.

P.S.
I also noticed that if I change one of the pages, for example, with a CupertinoPage it works!

```
case SelectedPage.home:
          return [
            const CupertinoPage(
              child: MyHomePage(title: 'Hello',),
            ),
          ];
        case SelectedPage.addCardToCollection:
          return [
            const MaterialPage(
              child: Page2(),
            ),
          ];
      }
```

Result:

[image]